# Change REST URL depending on called URL

Tags: java, rest

I currently have a problem with a REST service: The basic construction is the following: On my Tomcat there are running 2 applications (my new REST service (S1) and another application (S2) which also offers REST calls). The Applications should work together so that S1 can send requests to S2. It works fine if I use hard coded URLs in S1 to call S2. But the problem is that the path of the applications are changing due to different ports or configurations. The changes apply to both applications since they are both on the same Tomcat server.
Basically the 2 Paths look similar, starting e.g. with `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://sys-example:8034/`. So if I call S1 on an specific Path, the application should fetch the URL and build its own basePath to reach S2 on the same Server. How can I create a method which gets me the path where my service is called. IS there a way to use `ServletContext` or is there a better way?

Currently this is my code in S1 to reach the service in S2

```
String path = configMap.get("basePath").toString(); 
//configMap is a HashMap which contains Data from an config file
//the result of get("basePath") looks like this: http://localhost:8080
path = path.concat("/otherService/rest/action/login");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the 2 servlets will run in the same Tomcat installation and, moreover, in the same context, I suggest using the direct interaction.

Please check the link at this [URL](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch11_01.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you are saying that you run the services in different environments, e.g. production, development, local etc., which means host and port differ. The relative paths to your services remain the same, though.

Then, it is absolutely ok to hard-code the relative paths since they don't change. The host and port, however, should be configurable. You could load them from the database, in case you have access to your database before you need those data.

Another solution might be to configure host and port within your web container. If you should use Tomcat as your web container, create a properties file and load it when the app is being bootstrapped.

EDIT:

Other answers suggest to resolve the path from the `request` object. I disadvise doing that for the following reasons:

- There might be use cases where you don't have a `request`. There might be (now or in future) other interfaces to your services than via HTTP
- You should not rely on what URL to call depending on the request coming in, since you have no control over that values. Think of Reverse Proxies or Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the REST call using an URI object. Example:

```
URI u = URI.create("http://www.example.com:8080/rest/service/call");
String restPath = u.getPath();
System.out.println(restPath);
```

This way, you can append the REST url easily to S2. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the required details from `HttpServletRequest` object.

The below code must give you the required details. I have not tested this, but this should get you started.

```
StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String host = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(uri));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `request.getRequestURL()` is what you want